# Slider to choose numbers between -24 and 24 with 0.5 step

Tags: android, android-layout, slider

I want to create slider that gives to the user an ability to choose numbers on a range of -24 to 24 with 0.5 steps. 
So that, I decided to create slider whose thumb is located at the center and could be slided to both left and right sides. Here's the picture of what I am aiming at:
[thumb is located at the center and user can move it to both sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SiMs.jpg)

When user moves the thumb of slider to the left it sets negative numbers. Similarly, when user moves it to the right it sets positive numbers.

How can I achieve this? 
Is there another better way to give a user such ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second question is a matter of taste i believe.

As for implementing the slider, you can use [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html). Since you have 0.5 step size and a range of 48, that would give you 96 discrete points. Set the max as 96 in the `SeekBar`. Implement `onProcessChanged` accordingly and you are good to go. See the example code for reference:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="-24"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:max="96"
    android:indeterminate="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="24"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

And here is the seek bar change listener:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SeekBar bar = (SeekBar)this.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        mTextView = ((TextView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.textView));
        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                float value = -24 + (progress / 2.0f);
                MainActivity.this.mTextView.setText(String.format("%.1f", value));
            }
        });
    }
}
```